fulfillRandomWords function of VRF2.5 not responding back after I override my custom logic
I'm creating a lottery contract using which I’m going to reward the participant with some ETH, and I’ve deployed the contract on Eth-Sepolia testnet.
I did a transaction with 2 participants (my two addresses), and it seems a random number was generated, and the contract tried to transfer ETH to my address(i.e., 0x2868571C….860CE4511), but failed, as you can see in the screenshot!

function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 participantCount = lotteryContract.participantCount();
        require(s_requests[_requestId].paid > 0, "request not found");
        s_requests[_requestId].fulfilled = true;
        s_requests[_requestId].randomWords = _randomWords[0] % participantCount;
        address winner = lotteryContract.participants(s_requests[_requestId].randomWords);
        (bool success, ) = (winner).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success, "ETH transfer failed");
        lotteryContract.doPostChanges();
        emit RequestFulfilled(
            _requestId,
            _randomWords,
            s_requests[_requestId].paid
        );
    }

Could anyone help me with this?

Can you please share the transaction hash?
